# Treeview of Checkbox

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, user-controls, treeview

I have created a user control consists of a `checkbox` control and a string which holds another value I would like to save for each `checkbox`.

The user is able to select or deselect the checkboxes.

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    private CheckBox c = new CheckBox();
    private string EAType;
}
```

However, there are a lot of them and the `Form layout` looks messy.
Therefore, I would like to classify them by criteria, organizing them in a `treeview`.

This is quite easy to set the `treeview` to `checkbox-treeview`, but, as mentioned, I have another string to store for each.

Is a `usercontrol treeview` possible? If yes, how?
Any other ideas are welcome...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need a `UserControl` just to store a string?

To add custom information to a `Control` you always have `Tag` property and to add custom information to a `TreeNode` you have `TreeNode.Tag` property (there you can store what you want, a class or directly your string).

```
foreach (var obj in objects)
    treeView.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode { Text = obj.Title, Tag = obj.Value });
```

In this example I have an hypothetical collection `objects`, `Title` property will determine `TreeNode` caption and I store another custom value (from `Value` property) into `TreeNode.Tag` property. If you want you can directly store object itself:

```
foreach (var obj in objects)
    treeView.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode { Text = obj.Title, Tag = obj });
```

To access them you'll need to cast to proper type, for example (with strings):

```
var checkedNodes = treeView.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>().Where(x => x.Checked);
var selectedValues = checkedNodes.Select(x => Convert.ToString(x.Tag));
```

Or, with objects:

```
var selectedValues = treeView.Nodes
    .Cast<TreeNode>()
    .Where(x => x.Checked)
    .Select(x => (YourObject)x.Tag);
```

Finally note that you may even use other list types:

- For a simple list of values you can use `ListBox` with checkboxes. Each item is an `object` and then it can be anything you want, just override `ToString()` to provide proper display text.
- For a more complex list (or with more items you want to organize in groups) you can use a `ListView`. Same technique we saw for `TreeView`, each `ListViewItem` has a `Tag` property you can use to store additional information. If you need just one level (multiple groups with a set of items) it may be more convenient than a tree view because customization is easier.

Whichever list you choose or you don't choose and you go with a plain `CheckBox` you don't really need a `UserControl`, in every control you have a `Tag` property for this purpose and for more complex situations you can derive directly from right control (`CheckBox`, for example) and add properties/methods you need. `UserControl` is (usually) used for composition when you need to have a control made of multiple ones for example to reuse some complex UI.